# Recursive complexity,the answer is wrong?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following code, and I want to find the complexity:

```
analizz(int n) 
    c = 1 
    k = n*n 
    while k > 1 do k = k - 2 
    for i = 0 to 1 do
    if n >1 then analizz(n/2)
```

The problem that the code written in this way ,and I'm trying to understand, the FOR loop is inside the while loop ,so the cost should be O(n^2) ,and one recursive call if n > 1, so T(n/2).

The answer should be T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn2 , I cannot understand how exactly 2T(n/2) ? if there is only one recursive call?

ps.I don't know which title will describe best my problem

Comment: It's not clear what that code means. Is the `for` loop *in* or *after* the while loop? Note, though, that the `for` loop always has 2 iterations, no matter what `n` is, so you could replace the `for` loop with 2 recursive calls to `analizz`.

Comment: @chepner ,thank you , now I realized that the if condition is inside the for loop and it does twice recursive call, thank you very much, but how the while loop is n^2?

Comment: Because `k = n * n = n ^ 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The code is written poorly, but if the answer is correct than the `for` is not inside the `while` loop and the `if` is inside the `for` loop. the `while` gives the `cn^2` and the two recursive calls are inside the `for` loop

Comment: Even if the `for` loop is in the `while` loop, the number of iterations is bounded by a constant (2).

Comment: Thank you Shuki for the answer, now I got  why there are 2 recursive calls, but how is the while loop is n^2?

Comment: the while loop is counting down from n^2 to 0 in steps of 2. there is nothing inside the loop, but the counting itself is (n^2)/2.

Comment: @shukiavraham so it depends of the previous line  k = n * n  if it was k = n * n * n
so n^3 ... I got it right?